# Switching Microsoft Access Query to ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server Returns No Records

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, odbc, adodb

We are in the process of changing to ODBC Driver 17 to have support for TLS 1.2, changing the provider from sqloledb to driver ODBC 17 causes the recordset to be empty.  The query executes, as I can see it in SQL Profiler, but no records are returned to Microsoft Access.  Here is the old connection string and the new one.

```
Dim connectionString As String
' old - this worked connectionString = "Provider=sqloledb;Server=SQL\SQLInstance;Database=databaseName;Trusted_Connection=yes;"    
connectionString = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=SQL\SQLInstance;Database=databaseName;Trusted_Connection=yes;"

Dim Rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

cmd.ActiveConnection = connectionString
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * From [dbo].[TableName]"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
Set Rs = cmd.Execute
```

Is there a different way to return the records using this?  I have simplified the question for troubleshooting purporses, the real case uses a parametrized stored procedure.

Comment: The `Server` is not the same in the two connection strings.  And the recommended replacement for `SQLOLEDB` is `MSOLEDBSQL` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: do the linked tables work with the 17 driver? Try linking a table - see that connection string. also, I believe that there are two native 17 drivers. One set of drivers does not include oleDB support - so you have to install the correct one. Linked tables use ODBC, and thus it is reocmmended to use DAO in place of ADO. However, if you going to use oleDB (ADO) then you need to install support for that - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/download-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft how does this change the above code, I have installed the 18.5 MSOLEDBSQL provider, do I just drop the connection string back to the original one?

Comment: Changing the connection string alone, doesn't seem to solve the issue, connectionString = "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Server=SQL\SQLInstance;Database=databaseName;Trusted_Connection=yes;DataTypeCompatibility=80;MARS Connection=True;"

Answer (score 1):

```
"Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Server=SQL\SQLInstance;Database=databaseName;
Trusted_Connection=yes;DataTypeCompatibility=80;MARS Connection=True;"
```

This ended up being the correct connection string, after following the link from @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, I needed to install the Microsoft OLE DB Driver 18.5 for SQL Server and reboot before it worked.